# Parsing SSH2 (RFC4716) Public Key

Tags: c++, ssh, cryptography

I've been working with the SSH2 File format and was trying to find a good way to parse out elements of the SSH2 public key to be left with the encoded base64 data.  I've been able to remove the file fields "---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ---- " and "---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----" but I've been wondering how to remove other potential data fields such as Comment : "foo" or Subject:"bar"

Comment: Are we to assume OpenSSL (and other such flavors of crypto libraries) are off the table?

Answer (score 0):

Discard all lines/continued-lines which are headers until you find one that's not a header, and what you're left with is the base64-encoded data.

From the RFC:

> A line that is not a continuation line that has no ':' in it is the first line of the base64-encoded body.

If you treat the line-continuation marker as having high-precedence lexically, it should be straightforward after that.